# ¿Cómo crear múltiples objetos JSON y llamarlos con AJAX de Jquery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Ya sé retornar datos de un objeto json (de manera básica), así por ejemplo:

```
//fichero ajax.php
$.ajax( {
  url      : "obj.json",
  type     : "post",
  dataType : "json",
  success  : function ( cuerpo ) {
    $( 'body' ).text( cuerpo.edad )
  }
} )

  //fichero obj.json
  {
    "edad" : 20
  }
```

Pero, algo que desconozco y me gustaría saber es cómo crear múltiples objetos json y cómo poder llamarlos.. Algo así por ejemplo:

```
//ESTE CODIGO CONTIENE ERRORES DE SINTAXIS
objeto 1 {
"prop1" : 1,
"prop2" : "hola"
}
objeto 2 {
"prop1",
"prop2"
}
```

y también multidimensionales:

```
//ESTE CODIGO CONTIENE ERRORES DE SINTAXIS
{
  {
   "prop1" : "value1"
  }
  {
   "edad" : 23
  }
}
```

Por favor si pudieran poner ejemplos sencillos.

Comment: Hola, para practicar la creación de cadenas json puedes utilizar https://jsonlint.com/, es muy útil para validar que los json estén correctamente estructurados.

Answer (score 1):

al parecer tienes problemas separando tus objetos JSON.
Puedes usar esta pagina como referencia
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Si son varios objetos a la vez, tienes que agruparlos en un arreglo, o sea entre [ ] y cada objeto separado por una coma, por ejemplo [ { .... }, {....}]

```
[
  {
    "prop1" : 1,
    "prop2" : "hola"
  },
  {
    "prop1": 2,
    "prop2": "adios"
  }
]
```

A lo que llamas multidimensional, creo que te refieres a anidar uno dentro de otro, y no tienes limite, incluso puedes tener 2 objetos diferentes en el mismo arreglo.

```
[
  {
    "persona" : {
               "nombre": "Juan",
               "edad": 10
             },
    "comida" : "tacos"
  },
  {
    "automovil": "Porsche",
    "costo": 1000000
  }
]
```

Tienes que ser muy cuidados con las comas, ya que pueden arruinar la estructura.

Comment: Agregale la llamada a las propiedades de los objetos multidimensionales para darte el check de mejor respuesta. Antes un chico me respondio y le iba a dar su check pero elimino la respuesta, no se por que. En fin, todo lo que me has puesto es sobre la creacion de los objetos multidimensionales pero quisiera que expusieras la llamada a esos objetos. Gracias.